# Elements with transform rotate get partially hidden outside container

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transforms

I'm not sure if I have some issues in my code or maybe I'm missing something.
My goal is a navbar in vertical fixed position with two list menus rotated:

- One of them I called '**navMain**' (Logo, proyects, contact).
- The other one is '**navSocial**' (instagram, facebook, behance).

Once I get that **navMain** to the top and **navSocial** to the bottom and centered in container, part of those nav is out of screen and I don't know how to solve that issue.

I'm not sure now but if in a future I want to add more links to those menus, part of them are going to be hidden as well.

So here is what I've done. I'll appreciate any aid. Thanks in advance and I'm sorry my English.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
}


header ul {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="navMain" role="navigation">
    <li class="logo"><a href="#">logo</a></li>
    <li class="works"><a href="#">works</a></li>
    <li class="info"><a href="#">info</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navSocial" role="navigation">
    <li class="instagram"><a href="#">instagram</a></li>
    <li class="facebook"><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
    <li class="behance"><a href="#">behance</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `rotate()` function of the `transform` property, the rotation of the element occurs, by default, from its current position with an axis point in the center of the box.

This means that your nav elements, which are pinned to the top and bottom edges of the container, when given `rotate(-90deg)`, will rotate in place one-quarter of a turn counter-clockwise, causing half of each element to disappear over the container's edge.

Imagine there's a pole going through the horizontal and vertical center of the element, and the element spins around that point.

This behavior is controlled by the **`transform-origin`** property, whose initial values are `50% 50%` (same as `center center` or just `center`), which represent the x- and y-axis offsets, respectively.

To keep your elements fully in view, you need to move the element away from the edge or modify the point of rotation.

Here's a basic example using `transform-origin`:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

header ul:first-child {
  transform-origin: 100% 330%;
}

header ul:last-child {
  transform-origin: 0% -200%;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="navMain" role="navigation">
    <li class="logo"><a href="#">logo</a></li>
    <li class="works"><a href="#">works</a></li>
    <li class="info"><a href="#">info</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navSocial" role="navigation">
    <li class="instagram"><a href="#">instagram</a></li>
    <li class="facebook"><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
    <li class="behance"><a href="#">behance</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Or, instead of using `justify-content: space-between`, which pins the nav containers to the top and bottom edges, use `justify-content: space-around`, which leaves a bit of space between the nav and the edge. This may be enough space to prevent an overflow when the rotation occurs.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around; /* adjustment */
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="navMain" role="navigation">
    <li class="logo"><a href="#">logo</a></li>
    <li class="works"><a href="#">works</a></li>
    <li class="info"><a href="#">info</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navSocial" role="navigation">
    <li class="instagram"><a href="#">instagram</a></li>
    <li class="facebook"><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
    <li class="behance"><a href="#">behance</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Or, you can use margins to push the elements away from the edges:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
}

header ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

header ul:first-child {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

header ul:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <ul class="navMain" role="navigation">
    <li class="logo"><a href="#">logo</a></li>
    <li class="works"><a href="#">works</a></li>
    <li class="info"><a href="#">info</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="navSocial" role="navigation">
    <li class="instagram"><a href="#">instagram</a></li>
    <li class="facebook"><a href="#">facebook</a></li>
    <li class="behance"><a href="#">behance</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

More information:

- [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) in MDN
- [`transform-origin`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/transform-origin/) in CSS-Tricks
- [`transform-origin`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#transform-origin-property) in W3C